# Error scaffolding an API Controller with Actions and Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am going through this tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
and running Visual Studio Community version 16.9.2.

When I try to add a scaffolded item, controller with API actions and Entity Framework, it says: "There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Install the package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design and try again."
The package, however, is already installed.  I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution.  And I restarted Visual Studio and then tried rebooting my machine.  Nothing seems to help.

Seems like this happened to me before but I think rebooting the machine worked.  Not this time.  I may try uninstalling and reinstalling the package.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked after uninstalling and reinstalling the package.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this here if someone ever runs in to the issue, it will always fail if there is an error message. Try to re-build the solution and see if that fixes it and then try again.